# Trying to show a set equality regarding sigma algebras

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X_{\alpha}$, $\alpha \in A $ be a collection. Let $ X = \prod_{\alpha} X_{\alpha} $. Suppose $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $ is $\sigma-$algebra on $X_{\alpha} $. The product sigma algebra on $X$ is $\sigma( \mathcal{E} ) $ where $\mathcal{E} = \{ \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}( E_{\alpha} ) : E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{M}_{\alpha}, \alpha \in A \} $. Where $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}: X \to X_{\alpha} $ is projection map $\pi_{\alpha} ( (x_{\alpha} )_{\alpha \in A} ) = x_{\alpha } $.

Problem: If $A$ is countable and we are Given the collection $\mathcal{F} = \{ \prod_{\alpha \in A} E_{\alpha} : E_{\alpha} \} $, I want to show that $\mathcal{F}$ generates $\sigma( \mathcal{E} )$. In other words, I want to show $\sigma( \mathcal{F} ) = \sigma ( \mathcal{E} ) $.

#### What I can do

First, I show $\mathcal{F} \subset \sigma( \mathcal{E} )$. This would imply $\sigma( \mathcal{F} ) \subseteq \sigma( \mathcal{E} ) $. So, to do this, I was given the hint that $\prod_{\alpha} E_{\alpha} = \bigcap_{\alpha} \pi_{\alpha}^{-1} ( E_{\alpha} ) $, but I cant see how this is true

As for the other direction, that is showing that $\sigma( \mathcal{E} ) \subseteq \sigma( \mathcal{F} ) $, my book says that this follows from this fact:

$$ \pi_{\alpha}^{-1} (E_{\alpha} ) = \prod_{\beta \in A} E_{\beta} $$
where $E_{\alpha} = X_{\beta} $ for $\beta \neq \alpha $.

Which is puzzling. Can someone explain this to me? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with the second expression since it implies the first.  We want to decode what 
    $$ \pi_{\alpha}^{-1} (E_{\alpha} ) = \prod_{\beta \in A} E_{\beta} $$
where $E_{\alpha} = X_{\beta} $ for $\beta \neq \alpha $ means.  Since $A$ is countable, there is a mapping from it to the positive integers so I will henceforth assume $A$ is the positive integers.  With that in mind, I'll rewrite this with different notation:
    $$ \pi_{\alpha}^{-1} (E_{\alpha} ) = \prod_{\beta < \alpha} X_\beta \times E_{\alpha} \times \prod_{\beta > \alpha} X_\beta$$
This expression is saying that in order for a point $x$ to be in the pullback of the set $E_\alpha$ you need to have the point's $\alpha$ coordinate to be in $E_\alpha$.  Its other coordinates are arbitrary.

Now we can use the above to rewrite
$$\prod_{\alpha} E_{\alpha} = \bigcap_{\alpha} \pi_{\alpha}^{-1} ( E_{\alpha} )$$
as
$$\bigcap_{\alpha} \left(\prod_{\beta < \alpha} X_\beta \times E_{\alpha} \times \prod_{\beta > \alpha} X_\beta\right)$$
Now we are taking all points with the requirement that $x_\alpha \in E_\alpha$.  This is precisely the product of the sets $\{ E_\alpha \}$.